# Can I apply a style to every instance of a search phrase in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Is it possible to find all instances of a search term and change the style only? e.g instead of finding every instance of John and replacing it with Steve, I want to replace John with **John**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the find/replace menu there is an option for "more". Within that there is an option for "format"

Answer (score 0):

To apply a new font or style to all instances of a search term using "Find and Replace":

- Hit `ctrl-H` to open the "Find and Replace" dialog box.
- Type in the word(s) in the "Find what" box that you want to search for.
- Type the word(s) that you want to replace in the "Replace with:" box.  You may leave this blank if it is the same word you want to replace but in a different style, font, etc.
- Hit <kbd>More >></kbd> to open search options...this expands the "Find and Replace" dialog box.
- To simply change a font...At the bottom of the newly expanded dialog box click <kbd>Format</kbd> and choose `Font...`.  The "Find Font" dialog box will open.
- Choose the desired font formatting *for the replacement word(s)*. Click <kbd>ok</kbd>.
- Or, you may replace with a style.  In the expanded dialog box click <kbd>Format</kbd> and choose `Style...`.
- Choose the desired style and click <kbd>ok</kbd>.
- Proceed with the search and replace.